# Move item down the page with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a dropdown menu that looks like the bootstrap drop down menu: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns

Is there a way in JavaScript to move the whole ul holding the dropdown below the drop down button. Here is my html:

```
<ul class="navbar">
  <li class="navbarItem">
    Dropdown
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li>
        Dropdown 1
      </li>
      <li>
        Dropdown 2
      </li>
      <li>
        Dropdown 3
      </li>
    </uL>
  </li>
  <li> About Us </li>
</ul>
```

So basically I would like to **move the ul down the page with javascript**.

Comment: Sorry... but what? The dropdown menu in bootstrap IS below the dropdown button

Comment: Your drop down ul is below the dropdown button

Comment: I would like to move it down dynamically, aka a bit lower without css.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you want to accomplish, plus a working example (http://jsfiddle.net) of what you got so far.. for example: specify do you want it a bit lower (use margin) OR you want at a specific offset from the dropdown button (different story)..

Comment: Why without css? This seems to be a perfect fit for css? Could i possibly ask for a screenshot of your current menu item/the way it currently renders, as the question is a quite unclear.... Well at least in terms of how I understand bootstrap to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to move the ul around would be to do this, though it needs JQuery:

```
$('dropdown').offset().top = $('dropdown').offset().top + 5;
```

JQuery can be installed by placing this on your page:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is wrong.. first you can't use offset() on a regular js DOM element, its a jquery function..

Comment: I think we should not assume the existence of jQuery when providing solutions. If you offer solutions based on jQuery, you should also say that jQuery is used.

Comment: Its ok I have JQuery installed, though yes i agree

Answer (score 0):

Example = click to move the ul

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <style type='text/css'>
            div.wrapper {position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100% }
            ul.navbar { position:absolute; }
        </style>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function MoveNavBar(e) {
                var navBar = document.getElementById('navBar');
                navBar.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
                navBar.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onclick='MoveNavBar(event);'>
        <div class='wrapper'>
            <ul class="navbar" id='navBar'>
              <li class="navbarItem">
                Dropdown
                <ul class="dropdown">
                  <li>
                    Dropdown 1
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Dropdown 2
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    Dropdown 3
                  </li>
                </uL>
              </li>
              <li> About Us </li>
            </ul>    
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```